# ASP.NET - Repeater flowing outside div

Tags: .net, html, repeater, html-table

I have a **table** inside a **repeater** inside a **div** in **asp**.

When filling the repeater, some of the table rows inside it are too large horizontally, so the whole repeater width is flowing outside the DIV.

I tried everything, but nothing works. this is my code:

```
       <div>
     <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterColors" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
       <table border="1" width="100%;"   >
         <tr>
         <th style="min-width: 62px; width: 62px;">Color Word ID</th>
         <th style="min-width: 62px; width: 62px;">Color English Meaning</th>
         <th style="min-width: 62px; width: 62px;"></th>
         <th style="min-width: 62px; width: 62px;"></th>
         </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>      
      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>  
         <td> <%# Eval("MsgColor_wordID")%></td>
         <td> <%# Eval("MsgColor_Eng")%></td>
         <td > <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnEdit" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC0000" CommandName="edit" CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("MsgColor_ID")%>' >Edit</asp:LinkButton></td>
         <td > <asp:LinkButton ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC0000" CommandName="delete"  OnClientClick="return confirm('This record will be deleted. Proceed?')" CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("MsgColor_ID")%>' >Delete</asp:LinkButton></td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
      </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
       </div>
```

This div and the whole code is inside one **div** :

```
<div id="container">
```

css:

```
   #container
   {
       text-align:left;
       background:#fff;
       border:1px solid #ccc;
       margin:0 auto 10px auto;
       width:641px
   }
```

Here's how this is being displayed when large data is in the first cell:
*(DIV is the white space.)*

[image]

Comment: You are giving fixed width values. What are you expecting the div and table to do, how do you want them to interact?

Comment: @Alexander I want the table's width NOT to surpass the Div width. Thats why I set it to 100%. 100% inside the div

Comment: @Alexander that's cause I tried both. I copied the earlier version. Sorry.

Comment: I can't see anything flowing outside the div. I think you need to post your entire markup and css.

Comment: That looks quite well on my end.

Comment: @Alexander well, it is fine really, until the data is too large horizontally.

Comment: @Alexander Check the picture I just uploaded please.